# Export symbology for each layer in pdf

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology, pdf

I would like to make a pdf document with all the layers I have on my mxd.

The layers are represented according to a classification, this classification is different from one layer to another.

When I export in pdf, I have a document with all the layers, but I don't have any symbology for the layers, so I couldn't read the information that each layer represents and I could not add a legend, because I have several layers.

Someone have a solution.

[image]

Comment: What prevent you to add a legend ? if you use a different color scheme for each layer there wont be any confusion

Comment: I can't use legend, because I have more than 20 layers.
I'am representing chemical parameters and I would like to make an atlas of maps by each parameters and for each parameter(layers) its legend or symbology

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use the Data driven page.

- First create 20 identical overlapping polygon (one for each of your layer) and the same extent as your final map then create an attribute referring to your layer (for exemple poly 1 = Na, poly 2 = SO4, poly 3 = K, ...)
- then create a field in each of your 20 layer and fill with the attribute you define in step 1 (so for exemple each of your object in the Na layer as a Na attribute)
- Set the data driven page and create a page definition query on each of your layer, the goal being that only one of your layer is visible on each page
- Create a legend with all your layer but with the options to only show what is visible on the map

you should be able to export 20 pdf (or one pdf with 20 page), each one showing only one of your layer with the corresponding legend

Comment: after sleeping on it it seem a lot simpler to just manually create the 20 map by checking/unchecking the layers..., you got the same result but have a lot less work.

Answer (score 0):

There are two suggestions:

First: by defining your legend in rectangular left/right your map as something like following; so it's enough clearly even for more than 20 layer

[image]

Second: using ArcReader, it's a good option to provide other users with your map, legend and other data; something like following:

[image]

Comment: Ok, I will test and I will come back if needed, thank you.